# Php validation error when form submit

Tags: php

The following code does not work as intended, when the submit button of the form is clicked it with no data entered it goes to blog.php instead of showing the error above the form?

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('connection.php');



if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    //display index
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

linked with the following html form

```
  <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error;  ?> </small>
  <?php } ?>


  <form action="blog.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
  </form>
```

Comment: the code is from admin.php

Comment: You could redirect back to the login page from the PHP that tests for the two inputs with a header('Location: login.php?error='.$error) if an error occurs.

Comment: i dont think $error is receiving a value whatever is wrong

Comment: It won't receive a value because `blog.php` doesn't know the variable `$error` from `admin.php`

Comment: yeah that was silly, getting late... thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If the actual validation is being done in `admin.php`, shouldn't the `action` be pointing to `admin.php`?

```
  <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error;  ?> </small>
  <?php } ?>


  <form action="admin.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
  </form>
```